# Add and Remove DOM element dynamically using alpine JS

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

lets say I have 3 radio button with value 1, 2, 3.

When I click radio button of value 2, I need to create 2 div.

When I click radio button of value 1, hence I need to remove 1 div.

For now, the above scenario is done as below:

```
<template x-for="i in radioValue" x-init="$watch('radioValue', value => console.log(value))">
    <div class="bg-white rounded-md h-full w-full"></div>
</template>
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you want to achieve. But this does what you asked for:

```html
<form x-data="{radioValue: null}">

    <fieldset x-model="radioValue">
        <input type="radio" name="radioInput" value="1">Radio 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioInput" value="2">Radio 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioInput" value="3">Radio 3<br>
    </fieldset>

    <hr>

    <div x-show="radioValue!='1' && radioValue!=null">Div no.1</div>
    <div x-show="radioValue==='2' || radioValue==='1'">Div no.2</div>
    
</form>
```

You can get the selected value of radio buttons and store it in a variable using `x-model` and then based on that, decide to show/hide which other elements.